# Printing each row separately

Tags: python, row

I am very new to python, and needed to create the following chart given the columns. Now, I need to print each row independently. How could I do that given where I am now? Is it possible from this point or is there a better way to create the chart?

I have searched for solutions but since I'm just now learning, I'm mostly clueless as to what can be done.

this is what i have now

```
    t160 = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
    t170 = [2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
    t180 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    t190 = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]

    test = zip(t160,t170,t180,t190)

   fmt = '{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}'
   print(fmt.format('','160','170','180','190'))
   for i, (t160, t170, t180, t190) in enumerate(test):
        print(fmt.format(i, t160, t170, t180, t190))
```

which produces a result like

```
         160   170   180   190
   0     1     2     1     2
   1     1     2     2     1
   2     3     3     3     3
   3     1     2     2     1
   4     1     2     1     2
```

Now, I need to end up with each row individually. 
So, Something like

```
   r1 = [1, 2, 1, 2]
   r2 = [1, 2, 2, 1]
   r3 = [3, 3, 3, 3]
   r4 = [1, 2, 2, 1]
   r5 = [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

or at least something of that nature but I have no clue where to go next. Any advice would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: As this looks like transpose, I recommend using indices-based iteration ("C and the likes" style). In this case, you'd simply swap `row` and `column` indices to get a transposed matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
r1, r2, r3, r4, r5 = test
```

But, I believe there's no point in using different variables for each row. You can get individual rows separately with:

```
rows = list(test)
print(rows[0])  # First row
print(rows[1])  # Second row
# ...
```

So, in general to get `n`th row:

```
row[n-1]
```

Note that a `zip` object can only be consumed once.

Answer (score 0):

It should do exactly what you want :)

If you don't have numpy library: pip install numpy
(I use python 3.)

```
import numpy as np

t160 = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
t170 = [2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
t180 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
t190 = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]  


results = np.zeros((4,5))
results[0,:] = t160
results[1,:] = t170
results[2,:] = t180
results[3,:] = t190

for i in range(0,5):
    print("r{} = {} ".format(i+1, results[:,i]))
```